# Display single row by specifying line number?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I want to display content of a file. The way I wanted is, when I specify a line number, it should show only that row. For example the content in a file named "FILE" are as follows:

```
/home/john
/home/mathew
/home/alexander
/home/testuser
/home/hellouser
```

I want to display single row at a time by giving line number, like If I specify 3, it should show only following row.

```
/home/alexander
```

I know another way is possible with head and tail using -n flag, but that just display the entire rows upto the line number we specify, like as follows.

```
head -n3 FILE
/home/john
/home/mathew
/home/alexander
```

I don't want that, I want only to display "`/home/alexander`" only the when I choose line number 3. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

with `head` and `tail` you can do the following:

```
head -3 FILE | tail -1
```

Comment: It worked, thank you :) but can you explain what's that tail -1 does here, how it helps head commend to hide rest two lines?

Comment: `tail` is the opposite of `head`: it prints the *last* `n` lines -- "give me the first 3 lines, then the last line of those"

Comment: you pipe the output of `head` (the first three lines of FILE) to `tail` which picks only the last line (because of option "-1")

Answer (score 2):

Some other ways (4th line):

```
sed -n '4p' file
```

or

```
perl -ne 'print if 4 == $.' file
```

or

```
grep -n ^ file | grep '^4:' | cut -d: -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`

```
line=3
awk -v var="$line" 'NR==var' file
```

It will display the line number stored in variable `line`